# Django CMS per-site cache not working for CMS pages

Tags: django, caching, django-cms

I'm trying to setup Django's per-site cache (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache) with Django CMS and I can't get the cache to work for the CMS pages, however it works for apphooked pages.

This is a snippet of my settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'htmlmin.middleware.HtmlMinifyMiddleware',
    'htmlmin.middleware.MarkRequestMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 60
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = 'mysite-'
CMS_PAGE_CACHE = True

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'cache_table',
        'TIMEOUT' : 60*60*24,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 10000,
        }
    }
}
```

If I navigate to an apphooked page, the response header is:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=60
```

Which is correct. However with a CMS page I get the header:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
```

Which is incorrect.

The Django CMS documentation (http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/caching.html) says that the UpdateCacheMiddleware should be first FetchFromCacheMiddleware last, which is what I've done and have no luck.

I've restarted the server, tried updating content on the page and re-publishing but still having no luck.

What am I missing here?!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you logged in the CMS and in Page edit mode? When you check?

Comment: No I'm not, the headers I've pulled from a different browser where I'm not logged in. Thanks

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many hours of pain and suffering, I've finally managed to figure out the problem here. The problem was due was to the fact that I had a few custom plugins that I had set to not cache, eg:

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool

class MyPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    name = 'My plugin'
    cache = False
    ...

plugin_pool.register_plugin(MyPlugin)
```

On pages where there is a plugin set to not cache, the cache-control header is showing as:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
```

Which I suppose is correct. If you remove the plugin from that page, you get the expected header:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=60
```

Hopefully this helps somebody else one day.